# What are the best answers to these questions appear on recommendation letter

Tags: recommendation-letter

I am unsure about the following questions:

1. "During which period of time have you had the most frequent contact with the appliacant?
   From ___  to  ___ ."

What am i supposed to answer? Date, days, time? Anything else?

2. "What was the nature of your relationship?"

What does it mean?

3. What is family name?

Is that a name we got from father?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is about time, but it can be pretty general. A range of months, or even years.

The second might be something like "I was the student's professor in three economics courses" or colleague. Professional relationships are best.

The last is culturally determined and can vary widely. Your suggestion is pretty close to accurate if it is meaningful to you. In Europe, it is usually the "last" name. In Asia, usually the "first" name (also in Hungary). Some other places it is actually the father's "given name". Perhaps it is a name you would share with your siblings. Or the name you are indexed by in scientific publications.

The fictional *Kristin Lavransdatter* was the daughter of Lavrans, in Scandinavia. But her brother would have been *... Lavransson*. Do your best with this one if you are from a distinct culture.

Comment: If i met the applicant since 2013-2017 i write "from 2013 to 2017 " ?

Comment: That works if you had at least periodic contact through the period.